# Sending GET request while POST RequestMethod set

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a problem with sending POST requests through browser. Here is piece of code where I set parameters:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/abc/def/{parameter}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<classA> function(@PathVariable(value = "parameter") String parameter) { ... }
```

I want to send POST request but when I write in browser:

```
https://localhost:1234/abc/def/1
```

I get `Request method 'GET' not supported`.

I don't want to send GET request, but POST and there comes the question.

Comment: Why did you think writing a URL in your browser's address bar would send a POST request?

Answer (score 0):

Use curl command line tool or try RESTClient add-on for Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpRequester - plugin for FireFox. There is an option to sent POST/GET/PUT request. Even XML file as an input.

greets

Answer (score 0):

When you type URL in browser by default `GET` method would be called. In order to invoke `POST` method you will need to try tools like POSTER, RESTClient in mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Postman client for sending `POST/GET` and other request,when you type the URL in browser ,a `GET` request is generated